# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/ 400 (Unauthorized)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, angular6

**view.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited. """

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserRegister.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateRegister,)
```

This is the view.py file. Here i have added authentication and permission to my view set.

**permission.py**

```
class UpdateRegister(permissions.BasePermission):
    """ Allow user to edit their own profile. """

    def has_object_permissions(self, request, view, obj):
        """ Check user is trying to edit their own profile. """

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.id == request.user.id
```

**serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRegister
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Create and return a new user"""

        user = UserRegister(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

[Error shown in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSLbS.png)

So guy i am being bother by this error. Hope you guys will address my mistake and help me to solve the error.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'UserRegisterManager' object has no attribute 'create_user'` is quite right. You don't have it. What you have is `createUser` in camelCase

Comment: And again, the title of the question says 401 unauthorized but from the screenshot you added, what you get is 400 bad request. Can you outline your questions clearly at the end because it seems you have many. Also add the payload you're posting from the client

Comment: @Ken4scholars. Thanks for the response. first problem is solved. I don't understand the payload. If you are talking about the front end side i am pretty sure i have no error from the front end side.

Comment: The request body that you are posting. Again, outline the problems you're having. 401 or 400?

Comment: @Ken4scholars its a 400 error. And request body is POST.

Comment: Can you eliminate not relevant (fixed) issues from your question and update info about current issue?

Comment: Ok but 400 is not unauthorized error, that is 401. 400 is a more generic error which in DRF is mostly used for input error. From the error, it says you have not provided the necessary data needed and since you have not posted your request body as I requested, I don't really see how I can help here

Comment: From what I can make out is, that your serializers are throwing the error. Apparently, your request body does not consist of the required data ie email and password. In case it does contain the data in the proper format, the issue surely lies in the UserSerializer.